# How to pattern match types conforming to a protocol

Tags: swift, pattern-matching, protocols

I would like to write functions that match a type pattern like this (just example code):

```
protocol Event {}

enum LightsEvent: Event {
    case SwitchOn
    case SwitchOff
}

enum CameraEvent: Event {
    case Rolling
    case Cut
}

struct EventHandler {
    let event: Event

    func handle(event: LightsEvent) {
        // do something with lights
    }

    func handle(event: CameraEvent) {
        // do something with camera
    }
}

let handler = EventHandler(event: LightsEvent.SwitchOn)
handler.handle(handler.event) // error: Cannot invoke 'handle' with type ('Event')
```

I feel like it should compile, but it doesn't. This forces me to add a switch function like so:

```
func handle(event: Event) {
        switch event {
        case let e as LightsEvent: handle(e)
        case let e as CameraEvent: handle(e)
        default: fatalError()
        }
    }
```

But I don't want to add another case to this switch each time I add another type of event to my handler. Does anyone have an idea how this can be solved more elegantly?

Comment: If *elegancy* is the goal, change your enums, they are nor elegant in the first place.

Comment: @luk2302 actually you'd be surprised of how elegant you can solve problems in `Swift` by using enums (with or without associated values) and pattern matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding generics to `EventHandler` will make it work:

```
struct EventHandler<T: Event> {
    let event: T

    func handle(event: LightsEvent) {
        print("lights: \(event)");
    }

    func handle(event: CameraEvent) {
        print("camera: \(event)");
    }
}

let handler = EventHandler(event: LightsEvent.SwitchOn)
handler.handle(handler.event)
```

However this is still not elegant enough, as we pass the same event twice, when constructing the `EventHandler`, and when calling the `handle` method.

You can also not keep a reference to the event in `EventHandler`, as it might not be needed, and simply ask to handle it:

```
struct EventHandler {

    func handle(event: LightsEvent) {
        print("lights: \(event)");
    }

    func handle(event: CameraEvent) {
        print("camera: \(event)");
    }
}

let handler = EventHandler()
handler.handle(LightsEvent.SwitchOn)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol Event {}

enum Events : Event {
    case One, Two
}

struct EventHandler {
    let event: Events

    func handle<T: Event>(event: T) {
        print(event)
    }
}

let handler = EventHandler(event: Events.Two)
handler.handle(handler.event) // prints "Two"
```

However if you just want to use the protocol as an empty dummy type constraint, you might as well remove it and just the enum

```
enum Events {
    case One, Two
}

struct EventHandler {
    let event: Events

    func handle(event: Events) {
        print(event)
    }
}

let handler = EventHandler(event: Events.Two)
handler.handle(handler.event) // prints "Two"
```

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more clear what I want. I want to be able to route different types of events through a top-level event manager.